# Find an analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analyticity

**Let $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}z^j$ for $|z|<1$. For what values of $\alpha$ ($|\alpha|<1$) does the Taylor expansion of f(z) about $z=\alpha$ yield a direct analytic continuaton of f(z) to a disk extending outside $|z|<1$?**

I thought that the answer would be $\alpha=0$ since then the function f(z) would be constant. And like a zero degree polynomial it would be analytic in the entire complex plane and thus have extended the function to be total. But the answer key says $-1\leq\alpha<0$, what is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: It looks like you're confused about $\alpha$.  Note that this $\alpha$ just represents the center for a Taylor series expansion.  So, for example, at $\alpha = 0$, we just get the original function $\sum z^j$.  For different $\alpha$, we'll get different power series representations for $f$ (centered at $\alpha$).  The question is: which of these recentered power series extend $f$ outside of the unit circle?

Comment: Do you know of a function that $f$ represents on the unit disk?  That might be a good place to start.